# $resource posts empty object in Internet Explorer

Tags: angularjs, wcf, internet-explorer

I have an issue with Internet Explorer 11 and `$resource` service in Angular 1.4.9. My code calls web service to post some object:

```
var FooServiceHandle = $resource('some/Address/');
var fooServiceHandle = new FooServiceHandle ();

fooServiceHandle.bar = someData;

fooServiceHandle.$save().then(function () { console.log('saved') });
```

Web service on the other hand is WCF REST.

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(RegistrationNotAllowedFault))]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "some/Address/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
string Foo(Bar bar);
```

When I use IE the argument of the Foo method in the web service is null (but service method is called). Just before the `$save` call `fooServiceHandle.bar` variable isn't undefined, but a proper object. My code works in Chrome 48 and Firefox 44.

**UPDATE**

Strange thing is that when I look at network tab of IE developer tools it shows proper request body (which is JSON). Moreover when I copy-paste that request body to SoapUI it executes correctly. HTTP method of IE request is ok (POST), also content type (application/json). First IE request has result 307 and later there goes another with 400.

[image]

**UPDATE2**

I can't see any major differences in request between Chrome and IE except one - in IE order of JSON keys is slightly different, however structure is all right.

**UPDATE3**

Exactly the same issue with $http service. In Chrome it works and WCF binds an object, in IE it doesn't and gets null argument in service method.

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'some/Address/',
    data: { bar: someData}
}

$http(req).then(function(){console.log('saved')}, function(){});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of this issue is pretty unbelievable. Somehow Internet Explorer and WCF together cannot handle slash at the end of service method address. Removing backslash eliminates the problem:

```
UriTemplate = "some/Address/" => UriTemplate = "some/Address"
var FooServiceHandle = $resource('some/Address/'); => var FooServiceHandle = $resource('some/Address');
```

In both Chrome and Firefox backslash is not a problem, probably they trim it.